# What does 001b mean in "exception in module kernel32.dll at 001b:7c812afb"

Tags: windows, exception, kernel, crash-reports, cpu-registers

For example:

> myapp.exe caused a Microsoft C++ Exception (0xe06d7363)  in module
>   kernel32.dll at 001b:7c812afb.

I'm asking this out of curiosity, because I've noticed that in all exceptions and crashes this number (001b) always stays the same, while the latter number changes (I assume it holds the instruction pointer's value).

So what does this 001b mean, exactly?

Comment: I guess its code segment pointer part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing an address of the form `CS:EIP`, where on your processor `CS` corresponds to the 16-bit Code Segment register and the `EIP` is the 32-bit Instruction Pointer (it would be just `IP` in a 16-bit mode).

That's the part I knew before looking into why you are seeing a `CS` of `0x001b` (`0b0000000000011011`) in all the cases you're studying.  Anything else I'm about to say is semi-informed guess-work and/or wild speculation.  I'm kind of following along with these:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410/doc/segments/segments.html

So here goes nothing.  Just add a "maybe" after every sentence I'm about to say, and someone who does this kind of work for serious can step in and correct the mistakes...

---

In protected mode, the lower two bits of the `CS` register are the `RPL` or "Requested Privilege Level".  The protection rings are:

- 0 - Operating System Kernel
- 1 and 2 - Operating System Services
- 3 - Applications

You're in 3 (`0b11`) because presumably these are applications that are crashing while calling a system DLL.  That's in contrast to...say...the OS itself having a bug--which would be giving you a blue screen of death instead of a nice Windows dialog.  In fact, if you Google around for some blue screens they often start with `0x0028` (`0b0000000000101000`) and we can see that's a kernel-level crash.

The next most significant bit is the `TI` or "Table Indicator"...which is either 0 for the *global descriptor table* or 1 for the *local descriptor table*.  (This provides a way of interpreting the meaning of the index held in the remaining upper 13 bits of the `CS` register we haven't talked about yet.)

In the crash you're seeing you've got 0 in the third bit to indicate use a global descriptor table.  That's because every app doesn't load its own copy of the same DLL, and your crash is happening inside of a DLL (presumably of it being passed improper data from your app).  If your crash was in the code of an EXE we'd expect this to be a 1.  My Windows experience is hazy but I seem to remember you get a different sort of message when the crash is actually in your program, and you don't get the `CS` register output like you do when it happens in a DLL.

Now we're left with the rest of it.  Index 3 (`0b0000000000011`) in the Global Descriptor Table.  Wazzat mean?  Don't have the source code for Windows on hand, but I did find some references in this kernel tutorial:

http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/4.-The%20GDT%20and%20IDT.html

If you look into the `init_gdt()` from that, you see:

```
gdt_set_gate(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);                // Null segment
gdt_set_gate(1, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x9A, 0xCF); // Code segment
gdt_set_gate(2, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x92, 0xCF); // Data segment
gdt_set_gate(3, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFA, 0xCF); // User mode code segment
gdt_set_gate(4, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF2, 0xCF); // User mode data segment
```

So Windows might use similar numbers (or even the same).  Perhaps `kernel32.dll` is running the  user mode code segment because it hasn't validated the stuff you passed into it yet enough to switch over into code segment 1.

...maybe.  :-P

Comment: Pretty much spot on. The only thing I'd add is to clarify your point at the end. Kernel32.dll is a user mode component and only ever runs in Ring 3.